# ORA-02292: integrity constraint, when refreshing materialized view

Tags: oracle

Oracle Production Version 19.17.0.0.0

I have a table with a foreign key to a materialized view, which is populated from a parent table.

Deleting and re-inserting the same record on the parent table (which shouldn't cause any difference in the materialized view) causes the foreign key to break.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEMP_20230509_PARENT
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
VALUES (1);
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TEMP_20230509_PARENT WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY;

-- MV pointing to the Parent
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV AS
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_20230509_PARENT;

-- child table that points to the MV
CREATE TABLE TEMP_20230509_CHILD
(
    ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PARENT_ID INT,
    CONSTRAINT TO_PARENT_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID)
            REFERENCES TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV (ID)
);

-- child record pointing to the MV
INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_CHILD
VALUES (1, 1);

-- insert new record in parent, should not affect the child
INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
VALUES (2);
--  full refresh works
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV');
END;

-- delete and reinsert the same record on the parent table
DELETE
FROM TEMP_20230509_PARENT A
WHERE A.ID = 1;
INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
VALUES (1);
COMMIT;

--  full refresh fails
-- ORA-02292: integrity constraint (IMPACT_NG.TO_PARENT_FK) violated - child record found
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as if MV refresh first *removes* rows (which is what raised the error because it really removed parent key) and then *inserts* them back.

Here's a workaround, see if it helps: create foreign key to be `INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE`.

---

Parent table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEMP_20230509_PARENT
  2  (
  3      ID INT PRIMARY KEY
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
  2  VALUES (1);

1 row created.
```

MV log:

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TEMP_20230509_PARENT WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY;

Materialized view log created.
```

MV itself:

```
SQL> -- MV pointing to the Parent
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV AS
  2  SELECT *
  3  FROM TEMP_20230509_PARENT;

Materialized view created.
```

**Child table** - note line #8:

```
SQL> -- child table that points to the MV
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEMP_20230509_CHILD
  2  (
  3      ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  4      PARENT_ID INT,
  5      CONSTRAINT TO_PARENT_FK
  6          FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID)
  7              REFERENCES TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV (ID)
  8              INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE              --> here
  9  );

Table created.

SQL> -- child record pointing to the MV
SQL> INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_CHILD
  2  VALUES (1, 1);

1 row created.
```

New parent row:

```
SQL> -- insert new record in parent, should not affect the child
SQL> INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
  2  VALUES (2);

1 row created.
```

Refresh:

```
SQL> -- full refresh works
SQL> BEGIN
  2      DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Delete / insert into the parent:

```
SQL> -- delete and reinsert the same record on the parent table
SQL> DELETE
  2  FROM TEMP_20230509_PARENT A
  3  WHERE A.ID = 1;

1 row deleted.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEMP_20230509_PARENT (ID)
  2  VALUES (1);

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

This is what **previously failed**, but now works:

```
SQL> -- full refresh WORKS
SQL> BEGIN
  2      DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

That's it.